# Getting the NSWindowController of an NSWindow returns nil

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow, nsviewcontroller, nswindowcontroller

I want to be able to retrieve the `NSWindowController` of a specific class of window opened by my app, returning the customer class of that window. The code walks through the window list, looking for the target view controller by calling `-[NSObject isKindOfClass:]`, then returns the window controller when the target view is found. However, when I attempt to get the window's controller, `windowController` returns `nil`.

```objc
- (MyWindowController *) retrieveMyController {
    MyWindowController   *mwc;
    NSArray              *windows = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    NSWindow             *window;
    NSViewController     *view;
    NSInteger            count = [windows count];
    
    mwc = nil;
    while (count--) {
        window = [windows objectAtIndex:count];
        view   = window.contentViewController;
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]]) {
            mwc = [window windowController];
            return (mwc);
        }
    }
    return (mwc);
}
```

The window is created in a storyboard and appears to be hooked up correctly:  `MyWindowController` -> `NSWindow` -> `MyViewController`

Is there something I might be missing in retrieving my window controller from an `NSWindow`?

UPDATE:

Here's a little more information from the section of the storyboard that describes the window controller.

This first bit of code is for the window that returns nil when I attempt to get the window controller:

```
<!--Window Controller-->
<scene sceneID="d6J-4M-8Ta">
    <objects>
        <windowController storyboardIdentifier="Game Board" showSeguePresentationStyle="single" id="rtu-Zd-mSC" customClass="MyWindowController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
            <window key="window" title="Game Board" allowsToolTipsWhenApplicationIsInactive="NO" autorecalculatesKeyViewLoop="NO" restorable="NO" releasedWhenClosed="NO" visibleAtLaunch="NO" frameAutosaveName="" animationBehavior="default" tabbingMode="disallowed" id="Om0-DT-JQm">
                <windowStyleMask key="styleMask" titled="YES" closable="YES" miniaturizable="YES" resizable="YES"/>
                <rect key="contentRect" x="512" y="303" width="1440" height="860"/>
                <rect key="screenRect" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="2560" height="1417"/>
                <value key="minSize" type="size" width="1440" height="860"/>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="delegate" destination="rtu-Zd-mSC" id="hWs-pg-5hH"/>
                </connections>
            </window>
            <connections>
                <segue destination="dCc-Ee-tuh" kind="relationship" relationship="window.shadowedContentViewController" id="Zh5-ae-o9K"/>
            </connections>
        </windowController>
        <customObject id="QgT-xE-oJb" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="NSResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
    </objects>
    <point key="canvasLocation" x="-1549" y="1308"/>
</scene>
```

And this snippet of code is for another window in my app, but I am able to retrieve the window controller for this window:

```
<!--Window Controller-->
<scene sceneID="q0J-D1-Y9O">
    <objects>
        <windowController id="R9S-Kd-BY0" customClass="ProjectsWindowController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
            <window key="window" title="Projects" allowsToolTipsWhenApplicationIsInactive="NO" autorecalculatesKeyViewLoop="NO" releasedWhenClosed="NO" visibleAtLaunch="NO" frameAutosaveName="" animationBehavior="default" id="0gH-R3-7qL">
                <windowStyleMask key="styleMask" titled="YES" closable="YES" miniaturizable="YES" resizable="YES"/>
                <rect key="contentRect" x="933" y="448" width="650" height="522"/>
                <rect key="screenRect" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="2560" height="1415"/>
                <value key="minSize" type="size" width="650" height="200"/>
                <value key="minFullScreenContentSize" type="size" width="480" height="200"/>
                <view key="contentView" id="JTv-nd-FxB">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="650" height="522"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="delegate" destination="R9S-Kd-BY0" id="8fY-z4-N1F"/>
                </connections>
            </window>
            <connections>
                <segue destination="zDF-uA-d0p" kind="relationship" relationship="window.shadowedContentViewController" id="vxS-GV-TX6"/>
            </connections>
        </windowController>
        <customObject id="U0q-V5-uQM" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="NSResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
    </objects>
    <point key="canvasLocation" x="-3884" y="-2830"/>
</scene>
```

The difference that immediately stands out is that the first window controller lacks a  tag, which baffles me a little because the window certainly shows content, and when I walk through the code in the debugger [view isKindOfClass...] *does* return true.

(Editing this on a laptop right now that does not have Xcode installed, so I'll dig deeper once I'm home)

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me. How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: It works for me as well when tested against another window in my app, leading me to believe that there's something about the way this particular window is setup in my storyboard, but I've yet to discover the difference. I'm hoping someone else may have encountered something similar which may help uncover what I'm missing.

Comment: Updatesd with information from the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured this out. The reason why some of my windows would correctly return the window controller, while others return nil is due to how the windows are being created. Where my code looked like this...

```
    NSStoryboard *storyBoard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyWindow" bundle:nil];
    MyWindowController *mwc = [storyBoard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"Game Board"];
    [mwc showWindow:nil];
```

...Subsequent attempts to retrieve the window controller from the NSWindow in the window list would return nil. This is entirely due to the fact that the controller is being instantiated into a *local* NSWindowController. By instead instantiating into a property, everything works as expected and a legitimate window controller is returned by subsequent calls to [window windowController].

Even though we all know that the life of a local variable is limited to only the method in which the variable is declared, the behavior strikes me as a little weird. The window and all of its content IS created and continues to function long after the method that created the window has run. The NSWindow is still around, the content view is still around, and the window and all its controls (seems to) function flawlessly. The only thing that's missing is the linkage back to the window controller. I.m sure there's a good reason, but... weird.

Comment: For historical reasons and backward compatibility, the window isn't deallocated until it is closed. The normal ARC logic doesn't apply here.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that. Thanks!